# How to check if the value is number or string for a field with type 'character varying' in php?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am showing the list of 'locations' from the table 'Products'. Now this field 'locations' contains either a string value or a number. If it's a number, it refers to the id of the table 'free_shipping_locations' while if it's a string it refers to the location field of 'default_locations'. Now I have to display the 'locations' from the 'Products' table, but it should show the respective values, like if its a number it should show the location from 'free_shipping_location', if its a string than it should display that value. SO how can I check if the value of the field 'locations' is number or string. For Information: the datatype of 'locations' is `character varying`.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have any chance to change this database structure, do so. Having a single column with two completely different meanings will carry on making your life difficult for the lifetime of the application. Either put all the possible values in the referenced table and always store a `location_id`, or have two nullable columns, one `location_id` and the other `location_free_text`, with a constraint that every row has one or the other (and not both).

However, assuming you can't do that, the function you want in PHP is [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit):

> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical.

So it will return `true` for `'123'`, but `false` for `'abc'` or `'-1.2'`.

Note that it will error if given something other than a string, so often you will want to "cast" the argument with `(string)` to ensure it is:

```
 if ( ctype_digit((string)$your_value) ) {
      // It looks like an ID
 } else {
      // It's some other string
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to look up `character varying` in postgresql and my presumption is that PHP will **ALWAYS** receive a string from these column types so the solution is:

```
// Check if the string only contains digits
if( ctype_digit( $row[ 'locations' ] ) )
{
    // we have an ID!
}
else
{
    // we have some string which is probably not an ID!
}
```

Comment: `CHARACTER VARYING` is just the full name of the standard SQL column type commonly abbreviated to `VARCHAR`. It just means "variable length string".

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, that is my conclusion as well.